# what's the cause of this difference when encapsulating printf and vfprintf with another function?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, printf, variadic-functions

In this example this code although compiles it doesn't produce correct result:

```
void encapsulatePrintf(const char *str, ...) {
  va_list argptr;
  va_start(argptr, str);
  printf(str, argptr);
  va_end(argptr);
}
```

and then in main: `encapsulatePrintf("test str: %i - %s", 22, "test2");`

- the result is random bytes form somewhere in memory: `test str: 2293428 - á "`

but when I change the function from `printf` to `vfprintf(stdout, str, argptr);`

- all the output is ok.

What's going on here ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`printf()` doesn't take `va_list` as argument but rather a variable list of arguments while `vprintf()` takes a `va_list` as argument and not a variable list of arguments. Basically, when you called `printf()` using

```
printf(str, argptr);
```

you invoked undefined behavior: the first argument promised that you would pass an `int` and a `char*` but you passed, instead, a `va_list`. The types of the arguments passed to `printf()` have to match the specification in the format string.